# Variable Corrupted / Bloated

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, debugging, corruption

I have an app and some users experience an error where it seems a variable gets corrupted, causing the app to crash.  I am not sure what causes this corruption and have never been able to replicate the error on my test devices.

However today I got hold of a problem user's device and was able to perform `po brokenvar` in the console and got an output of the corrupted variable.

Here's the top 6 'lines' from the debugger:

`The N‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö√ë‚àö‚àÇ‚Äö√†√∂‚àö√´‚Äö√†√∂‚Äö√†√á‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö‚Ä†‚àö‚àÇ‚Äö√†√∂‚àö¬¥‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö‚Ä†‚àö‚àÇ‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö‚Ä†‚àö√°‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö√ë‚àö‚àÇ‚Äö√†√∂‚Äö√Ñ‚Ä†‚Äö√†√∂‚Äö√†√á‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö‚Ä†‚àö‚àÇ‚Äö√†√∂¬¨¬•‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö√ë‚àö‚àÇ‚Äö√†√∂‚Äö√Ñ‚Ä†‚Äö√†√∂‚Äö√†√á‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö√ë‚àö‚àÇ‚Äö√†√∂‚Äö√Ñ‚Ä†‚Äö√†√∂‚àö¬∞‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö√ë‚àö‚àÇ‚Äö√†√∂‚àö√´‚Äö√†√∂‚Äö√†√á‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö‚Ä†‚àö‚àÇ‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö√ë‚Äö√Ñ‚Ä†‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö‚Ä†‚àö‚àÇ‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö‚Ä†‚àö√°‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö√ë‚àö‚àÇ‚Äö√†√∂‚Äö√Ñ‚Ä†‚Äö√†√∂‚Äö√†√á‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö‚Ä†‚àö‚àÇ¬¨¬®¬¨‚Ä¢‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö√ë‚àö‚àÇ‚Äö√†√∂‚àö√´‚Äö√†√∂‚Äö√†√á‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö‚Ä†‚àö‚àÇ‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö√ë‚Äö√Ñ‚Ä†‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö‚Ä†‚àö‚àÇ‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö‚Ä†‚àö√°‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö√ë‚àö‚àÇ‚Äö√†√∂‚àö√´‚Äö√†√∂‚Äö√†√á‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö‚Ä†‚àö‚àÇ‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö√ë‚Äö√Ñ‚Ä†‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö‚Ä†‚àö‚àÇ‚Äö√†√∂¬¨‚àû‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö√ë‚àö‚àÇ‚Äö√†√∂‚àö√´‚Äö√†√∂‚Äö√†√á‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö‚Ä†‚àö‚àÇ‚Äö√†√∂‚àö¬¥‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö‚Ä†‚àö‚àÇ‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö‚Ä†‚àö√°‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö√ë‚àö‚àÇ‚Äö√†√∂‚Äö√Ñ‚Ä†‚Äö√†√∂‚Äö√†√á‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö√ë‚àö‚àÇ‚Äö√†√∂‚àö√`

And the bottom 6 'lines':

`´¬¨¬®¬¨¬Æ¬¨¬®¬¨√Ü¬¨¬®¬¨¬Æ¬¨¬®‚àö√ú¬¨¬®¬¨¬Æ¬¨¬®¬¨√Ü¬¨¬®¬¨¬Æ‚Äö√†√∂‚àö√∫‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö√ë‚àö‚àÇ‚Äö√†√∂‚àö√´‚Äö√†√∂‚Äö√†√á‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö‚Ä†‚àö‚àÇ‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö√ë‚Äö√Ñ‚Ä†‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö‚Ä†‚àö‚àÇ‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö‚Ä†‚àö√°‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö√ë‚àö‚àÇ‚Äö√†√∂‚Äö√Ñ‚Ä†‚Äö√†√∂‚Äö√†√á‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö‚Ä†‚àö‚àÇ‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö‚Ä†¬¨¬•¬¨¬®¬¨¬Æ¬¨¬®¬¨√Ü¬¨¬®¬¨¬Æ¬¨¬®‚àö√ú¬¨¬®¬¨¬Æ¬¨¬®¬¨√Ü¬¨¬®¬¨¬Æ‚Äö√†√∂‚àö√∫¬¨¬®¬¨¬Æ¬¨¬®¬¨√Ü¬¨¬®¬¨¬Æ¬¨¬®‚àö√ú¬¨¬®¬¨¬Æ¬¨¬®¬¨√Ü‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö‚Ä†‚àö‚àÇ‚Äö√†√∂‚àö‚à´¬¨¬®¬¨¬Æ¬¨¬®¬¨√Ü¬¨¬®¬¨¬Æ¬¨¬®‚àö√ú¬¨¬®¬¨¬Æ¬¨¬®¬¨√Ü¬¨¬®¬¨¬Æ‚Äö√†√∂‚àö√∫¬¨¬®¬¨¬Æ¬¨¬®¬¨√Ü¬¨¬®¬¨¬Æ¬¨¬®‚àö√ú‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö√ë‚àö‚àÇ‚Äö√†√∂‚Äö√Ñ‚Ä†‚Äö√†√∂‚Äö√†√á‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö‚Ä†‚àö‚àÇ‚Äö√†√∂‚Äö√†¬¥¬¨¬®¬¨¬Æ¬¨¬®¬¨√Ü¬¨¬®¬¨¬Æ¬¨¬®‚àö√ú¬¨¬®¬¨¬Æ¬¨¬®¬¨√Ü¬¨¬®¬¨¬Æ‚Äö√†√∂‚àö√∫¬¨¬®¬¨¬Æ¬¨¬®¬¨√Ü¬¨¬®¬¨¬Æ¬¨¬®‚àö√ú¬¨¬®¬¨¬Æ¬¨¬®¬¨√Ü‚Äö√Ñ√∂‚àö‚Ä†‚àö‚àÇ‚Äö√†√∂‚àö‚à´¬¨¬®¬¨¬Æ¬¨¬®¬¨√Ü¬¨¬®¬¨¬Æ¬¨¬®‚àö√ú¬¨¬®¬¨¬Æ¬¨¬®¬¨√Ü¬¨¬®¬¨¬Æ‚Äö√†√∂‚àö√∫¬¨¬®¬¨¬Æ¬¨¬®¬¨√Ü¬¨¬®¬¨¬Æ¬¨¬®‚àö√ú¬¨¬®¬¨¬Æ¬¨¬®¬¨√Ü¬¨¬®¬¨¬Æ¬¨¬®¬¨¬¢bel oven is marked but in good condition.`

There is *a lot* of more gibberish in the middle - I copied and pasted the whole lot into TextEdit and it turned out being a ~170mb text file.

You can see the start `The N` and the end `bel oven is..` which looks like the actual comment the user entered.

I did the `po brokenvar` output twice and compared the top/bottom 6 lines, they were exactly the same each time.  This makes me think that it is a saving issue that has occurred once, and not something that is getting corrupted on the fly - though I may be way off..

The user would have entered plain text into a UITextField, which gets saved into a SQLite database.  The crash occurs after reading the variable from the database, when I attempt to set the UITextField's text as the NSString.

The app is using a SQLite wrapper I found ages ago, lost the original link but found it here: https://github.com/ConnorD/simple-sqlite/blob/master/Sqlite.h

There doesn't seem to be any common thread with the handful of users who have experienced the problem.  It might be the first time they use the app, or the hundredth.

I'm not sure why it is coming out corrupt/gibberish/garbled like this, or where to move on from here.

Any suggestions on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm now checking the `length` of the bloated variable and handling it before it crashes the app - while this isn't ideal, it at least makes it manageable.  Any alternative ways on how to handle it or the root of the problem would still be fantastic.

Comment: I've got my hands on another user's iPad that is experiencing the same problem, but at a different stage. 

This one is having a huge memory spike (so much that it crashes) when it's running the SQL `select` query to get the data - as opposed to the first user's iPad who could get the data from SQL without problems but crashed when putting it in a `UITextField`.

This situation is even more frustrating as I can't think of a solution on how to detect a corruption before the code runs into it and the app crashes due to the hanging `select` SQL query.